# Recompose passing prop of an array of react elements

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, recompose

I started to use the recompose library, and it works great. But I am having some issues passing a default props of react elements.

flow error: call of mapOptions Function cannot be called on array type

```
    /* @flow */
import Input, { InputLabel } from 'material-ui/Input';
import Select from 'material-ui/Select';
import * as React from 'react';
import {withHandlers, withState, defaultProps, compose, withProps, mapProps} from 'recompose';
import { FormControl, FormHelperText } from 'material-ui/Form';
import {terms} from './Data/index'
import type { HOC } from 'recompose'

type Props ={
  // options: Array<React.Element<string>>,
}

const mapOptions = Object.keys(terms).map(key=>
  <option value={key}>{terms[key]}</option>
)

const BaseComponent = ({options})=>
        <FormControl>
           <InputLabel htmlFor="terms">Terms and Interest Rate</InputLabel>
           <Select
             native>
             {options}
           </Select>
       </FormControl>

const TermComponent: HOC<*, Props> = compose(
  defaultProps({
    options: mapOptions()
  })
)(BaseComponent)


export default TermComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like I had to call mapOptions as a literal because it was assigned to a variable. There was also an issue with type props not having options as a React.Node